# Dialog Box appears and then disappears

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I click on the button Dialog Box it appears and disappears, I tired using different plugins and hundreds of tutorial but dunno why things not working properly maybe because, I am using ASP.Net page and its inheriting from a masterpage

here's the code,

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubmit" runat="server">
<div id="question" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
        <h1>Would you like to contine?.</h1> 
        <input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes" /> 
        <input type="button" id="no" value="No" /> 
</div> 
   <input id="test" type="submit" value="Show Dialog" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.js

"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#test').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' } }); 
    }); 

    $('#yes').click(function() { 
        // update the block message 
        $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Remote call in progress...</h1>" }); 

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'wait.php', 
            cache: false, 
            complete: function() { 
                // unblock when remote call returns 
                $.unblockUI(); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 

    $('#no').click(function() { 
        $.unblockUI(); 
        return false; 
    }); 

}); 
</script>

<hr />
</asp:Content>
```

Its a jquery plugin I downloaded from here,

[Jquery Plugin I am using](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using

```
<input id="test" type="submit" value="Show Dialog" />
```

which cause postback due to which dialog disappear try

```
<input id="test" type="button" value="Show Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope it will work:

```
    $('#your form name').submit(function() { 
       $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' } });   
    });
```

Comment: I dont have any forms in current context, the page has content place holders , however master page has a form which i dunno if i can access

Answer (score 0):

your button `#test` is a submit button, that needs to prevent submitting to form if you want to see the message

try

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' } }); 
});
```